# How to transform ordinal age categories into a continuous variable?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a dataset in which the variable age is devided in three categories without any censoring in R. What is the best way to transform it to a continuous variable? Should I make dummy variables with 0,1,2 and put it as. numeric in my logistic regression model? If yes, what is the easiest way do do so in R? And how will it change the interpretation of the beta? In the model with age as categoric variable the beta is compared to the reference group. But how can be interpreted as continue? Per unit increase in age?

Comment: Is age the independent variable? Have you heard of the `ordinal` package?

Comment: Yes, age is one of the independent variables and the only ordinal variable. The other independent variables are also categoric but not ordinal. I haven't heard of the ordinal package.. Is there a function in it that is able to do the trick?

Comment: There is a tutorial here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf Other methods are discussed on stats stackexchaneg here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/continuous-dependent-variable-with-ordinal-independent-variable -- where this question maybe more suited.